# Extracting headers of msg outlook emails exported from "Sent folder" using msgxtractr package in R

Tags: r, email, outlook, msg

Using the msgxtractr package on R, I am trying to extract the headers of outlook emails with the format ".msg". The codes used are:

```
path = "C:/Users/.../email_for_extracting.msg"
library(msgxtractr)
email = read_msg(path)
email_header = email$headers
```

However, I notice that I am only able to do so if the email is located in the "Inbox" folder of my Outlook in the first place, and thereafter exported as a msg file. If the email is saved from the "Sent" folder, then email_header will be NULL.

Is there a way to extract the headers of emails located in the "Sent" folder of my Outlook? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent messages do not have the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property - it is only present on received messages when Outlook parses incoming messages and extracts the MIME headers. Sent messages might not even be converted to MIME, e.g. when sending between two Exchange mailboxes. Take a look at the messages with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button to see the available MAPI properties.